# Reflect a private methode of a implementation from an abstract class?

Tags: c#, reflection

How can I call private methode the base of one class?

Here is a basic example of my structure (that code is included with a reference):

```
public abstract class Something {
}
internal class ImplBase : Something {
    private void CallMe(string s) {}
}
internal class RealImpl : ImplBase {
}
```

So far I have an instanence of `RealImpl` which is visible as `Something`. How can I access the method `CallMe`?

I'm trying this code here:

```
Type type = obj.GetType(); // returns RealImpl
bool supported = false;
// a loop to be a little more flexible
for(Type t = type; t.Name != "Object"; t = t.BaseType) {
    if(t.Name == "ImplBase") {
        supported = true;
        type = t;
        break;
    }
}
if(supported) {
    var callme = type.GetMethod("CallMe", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { typeof(string) }, new ParameterModifier[] {});
    callme.Invoke(obj, new object[] { "hi" });
} else {
    throw new NotSupportedException("The type " + type.Name + " is not supported.");
}
```

If I comment out `type = t;` I'll get for `callme` a `null` value. If I use the code like here I get a Exception yelling about an internal `NullReferenceException`.

---

With my hack I produced a `NullReferenceException` inside the lib so far my fault. The code above is now fixed (there were 3 mistakes while simplifing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is named `callMe`, not `CallMe`, so change it like:

```
var callme = type.GetMethod("callMe"...
```

also invoke it on `obj` (not sure what `self` is):

```
callme.Invoke(obj, new object[] { "hi" });
```

additionally, you don't need all that code to determine if `obj` is `ImplBase` or not:

```
if(obj is ImplBase) 
{
    var callme = type.GetMethod("callMe", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, new Type[] { typeof(string) }, new ParameterModifier[] {});
    callme.Invoke(obj, new object[] { "hi" });
}
```

Comment: You pointed me to two small errors of my example code. That is not my error. But thank you anyway +1 :)
About your edit: I really love that `is` operator but the class `ImplBase` is internal of an external lib. So this won't work.

Comment: @rekire Your example code works fine with the changes I recommended. What is the error then?

Comment: That problems you pointed to are just stupid misstakes while making that problem more generic. My real code (just with other names like *self*) the code works. Except that I get `TargetInvocationException` with a inner `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @rekire something is wrong here. the base class cannot be less accessible (internal) than the derived class (public). It won't compile.

Comment: But so it is... The class `public abstract class XmlDictionaryWriter` is my `Something` and my `RealImpl` is the class `internal class XmlUTF8TextWriter`.

Comment: @rekire then it's not like what you're saying. The derived class is less accessible than the base class, which is perfectly fine. You might want to edit the question and change your example code to reflect your _exact_ problem, so that we can help you better.

Comment: That class seems not be be right initialted. So far my fault the code above itself works.

Answer (score 2):

If you need subclasses to call methods of their base classes you need to either declare those methods as `protected` or you need some kind of other method in the base class that stands as proxy for the private method.

```
public abstract class Something {
}
internal class ImplBase : Something {
    protected void callMe(string s) {}
}
internal class RealImpl : ImplBase {
}
```

or

```
public abstract class Something {
}
internal class ImplBase : Something {
    private void callMe(string s) {}
    public void CallMe(string s) { this.callMe(s);}
}
internal class RealImpl : ImplBase {
}
```

As far as I know, reflection will only work on public members/methods/etc. anyway.

Comment: That is not possible that classes are all defined in an external lib. Which I cannot edit just reflect.

Comment: About your edit: That is wrong is it possible to reflect private members with the flag `BindingFlags.NonPublic`. I mean I can "see" that method I just cannot call it ;-)

Comment: I did not know that, thanks for the clarification. However, accessing/calling private members would defeat the purpose of the private modifier.

Comment: Yes this is just for a small hack. I don't want to wrap a class and implement dozens of classes if I can just call one hidden function to solve my problem.